# jquery draggable li with image inside

Tags: jquery, css, draggable

I'm dynamically creating some li draggable elements. Everything works ok but now I want to dynamically insert an image inside those li's and be able o still drag and drop them.
Here is my working code:

```
    for( i = 1; i <= Num; i++) {
           $("#sortable").append("<li class='ui-state-default' id=" + i + ">" + "No" + i + "</li>");
         }
```

How can I do this?
Maybe with some inline css and the background-image style?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could dynamically assign a class with a background-image to the li. But then you have to know the size of the images.

But why not simply add an image?

```
$('li#idOfYourLi').html('<img src="pathToYourImg" />')
```

Comment: thanx for the reply. The background-image that i mentioned was just a thought..maybe it is better to just put an image. The images size is fixed and it the same size with li elements. Your code works as i want the only problem is that i want to do it inside the for loop. Can i do something like this?  $('li# + i + ').html('<img src="pathToYourImg" />')

Comment: The same loop as the one creating the lis? Then just add it to the html.
Otherwise use `$('#sortable li').each(function(){$(this).append('<img />');});`
BTW the id attribute has to begin with a letter